# Blender 2.9 How to use an Xbox joystick controller as an input to control an armature? (NOT GAME ENGINE)

Tags: python, rigging, armature

I’m trying to figure out how to use a joystick controller as an input device to control an armature. The idea is to assign the joystick (perhaps as a driver?) to a joint or bone and create a kind of puppeteering system where the keyframes get recorded in real time.

I'm using Blender 2.9 and so therefore NOT the old game engine.

So imagine the left joystick x direction maps to the x rotation of the bone, and the y direction controls the x rotation.

I found a python library called Inputs https://pypi.org/project/inputs/
but when I run it in Blender 2.9 it will show the results in the console, but it basically freezes Blender… and i don’t know how to grab the values and map them to my joint rotation position.

here is the code:

```
"""Simple example showing how to get gamepad events."""
#https://pypi.org/project/inputs/

from __future__ import print_function


from inputs import get_gamepad
myVal = 0

def main():
    """Just print out some event infomation when the gamepad is used."""
    while 1:
        events = get_gamepad()
        for event in events:
            if event.code == 'ABS_X':
                print('X position RAW: ')
                print(event.state)

                #need to add sume kind of conversion factor to map absolute values to degrees of rotation
                #need a way to store the values in a variable that Blender can access
            if event.code == 'ABS_Y':
                print('Y position RAW: ')
                print(event.state)

        #for event in events:
        #    print(event.ev_type, event.code, event.state)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work using the python package XInput.  I made a Youtube video ( https://youtu.be/Ng7E10a1brc) showing the process, not sure if I can post that as an answer so here is the method I used:

To install XInput I used the following code in Blender (run as administrator) adapted from https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/installing-python-packages-with-pip-in-blender-on-windows-10/:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os
 
python_exe = os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'bin', 'python.exe')
target = os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'lib', 'site-packages')
 
subprocess.call([python_exe, '-m', 'ensurepip'])
subprocess.call([python_exe, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'pip'])
 
subprocess.call([python_exe, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'XInput-Python', '-t', target])
 
print('FINISHED')
```

I then used the modal code from Blender developer site (https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/templates_py/operator_modal_timer.py) with some modifications - note that mine controls custom property fields that control drivers simulating a vehicle using rigid body physics in blender.  I used an XBox One controller.

```
import bpy
import XInput


class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs itself from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"

    _timer = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        #Controller Code
        state=XInput.get_state(0)
        bpy.data.objects["##Controller"]["TargetSpeed"] = 100
        bpy.data.objects["##Controller"]["ParkingBrake"] = 0
        if XInput.get_button_values(state)['A']:
             bpy.data.objects["##Controller"]["ParkingBrake"] = 100
        if XInput.get_button_values(state)['LEFT_SHOULDER']:
             bpy.data.objects["##Controller"]["TargetSpeed"] = -50
        bpy.data.objects["##Controller"]["Accel"] = XInput.get_trigger_values(state)[1]*100
        bpy.data.objects["##Controller"]["Brake"] = XInput.get_trigger_values(state)[0]*100
        bpy.data.objects["##Controller"]["Steering"] = XInput.get_thumb_values(state)[0][0]*100
        
        bpy.data.objects["##Controller"].location[0] = 0.00 # For some reason need this in here for it to update

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        
        #Reset rigid body physics simulation
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects["##Controller"]
        bpy.ops.rigidbody.constraint_add()
        bpy.ops.rigidbody.constraint_remove()
        
        #Play animation
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()
        
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.1, window=context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ModalTimerOperator.bl_idname, text=ModalTimerOperator.bl_label)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_view.append(menu_func)


# Register and add to the "view" menu (required to also use F3 search "Modal Timer Operator" for quick access).
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_view.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator()
```